# Changing Cursor of a button in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to change cursor of a button in MFC dialog. i have used

```
BOOL CStartDlg::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
if ( m_changeCursor )
{
    ::SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_HAND));
    return TRUE;
}

return CDialog::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
}
```

but it is changing cursor for whole dialog box. m_button is object of CButton class.
Please tell me how to change cursor of a button.I have tryed this also but not working

```
m_button1.SetCursor(::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the LoadCursor() function and pass its returned value to the CMFCButton::SetMouseCursor() member function. Here is an example:

```
BOOL CExerciseDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    m_Calculate.SetMouseCursor(LoadCursor(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
                               MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1)));

    return TRUE;
}
```

refer http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/mfcbtn.htm#subtitle

also refer [Api CWinApp::LoadCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class#loadcursor)

Comment: this method is valid only for CMFCButton class. Here m_button1 is object of CButton class.

Comment: myButton.SetCursor( ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND) ); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w6ks9y7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx