# MFC: CDialogEx with derived CButton child won't change cursor when over the button?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I want the cursor disabled when over the `CDialogEx` window but when over child buttons derived from `CButton` to show the standard cursor.

To get the mouse cursor to not show up, I had to override the `WM_SETCURSOR` message (registering a class with a `NULL` cursor didn't work).

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
  if (nHitTest==HTCLIENT) {
    ::SetCursor(NULL);
    return TRUE;
  }

  return CDialogEx::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
}
```

On the child buttons I have:

```
BOOL CMyButton::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
  HCURSOR hcursor=::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  SetCursor(hcursor);
  return TRUE;
}
```

But the mouse cursor doesn't show up when over the buttons?  The button function is called.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Cursor of a button in MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156092/changing-cursor-of-a-button-in-mfc)

Comment: Just disable the button like every other program, or select an X cursor. You shouldn't try to hide the cursor. The user will get very confused if the cursor disappeares all the sudden.

Comment: No, not really, as you can see above the CButton::SetCursor is called.   I draw my own complex cursor on the rest of the dialog that's why it's set to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `SetCursor()` call in the `CMyButton::OnSetCursor` to use `::SetCursor(hcursor)` instead.  The reason is `CButton::SetCursor()` doesn't set the cursor, it sets the image as in `BM_SETIMAGE` (as odd as that may be).

```
BOOL CMyButton::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
  HCURSOR hcursor=::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  ::SetCursor(hcursor);
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. This code is exactly the same as the code in the question.

Comment: @and Note the fully qualified function name. The question uses `SetCursor` (which calls [CButton::SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#setcursor)) whereas this answer calls `::SetCursor`, which invokes [SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor). With C++ you just never run out of sharp edges.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, the scope `::` ... I see now. Thanks. :)